# Is there a way to print all substrings of a string in O(n) time?

Tags: python, string, time-complexity, nested-loops

I have an input `abcde`. I'm trying to output something like this:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
b
bc
bcd
bcde
c
cd
cde
d
de
e
```

I can't make a code which is without nested loops. My question is what is the solution of this problem with *O(n)* time complexity?

My code is given below:

```py
s = "abcde"  
for i in range(len(s)):
    for x in range(i, len(s) + 1):
        a = s[i:x]
        if a != "": print(a)
```

Comment: If `n` is supposed to be the length of the input, that is impossible.

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: No,it doesn't matter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets do this without a nested loop!
This a game with `random` library, but the execution time is similar to your code.

```
from random import randint
list1=[]
str1='abcde'
while len(list1)!=int(((len(str1)+1)*len(str1))//2):
    i=randint(0,len(str1))
    j=randint(0,len(str1))
    i,j=max(i,j),min(i,j)
    if i!=j:
        a=str1[j:i]
        if a not in list1:
            list1.append(a)
            print(a)
```

if the string, `str1 = 'abcdef'`, it prints:

```
de
abcdef
cdef
abc
ef
d
c
abcd
b
abcde
def
bcde
f
bcdef
a
bcd
cd
e
ab
cde
bc
```

Now if you want your data in the order you specified, use `sort`:

```
list1.sort()
```

Comment: This is not `O(N)` as requested. It is `O(N^3)`.  There is no `O(N)` solution.

Comment: And doesn't even work.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to print all substrings of a string in `O(N)` time?

No there isn't.  It is mathematically impossible.

There are `O(N^2)` substrings of a string of length `N`.  You cannot print `O(N^2)` strings in `O(N)` time.  Not even if the strings were all (individually) `O(1)` to print.  (Which they aren't.  The average substring length is also a function of `N`.)

Even parallelism won't get you to `O(N)`.  If (hypothetically) had a `P > N` processors to generate the strings, *printing* them is a process that you cannot parallelize.

---

For the record, it is possible to code this in ways that avoid explicit nested loops.  But this doesn't alter the fundamental mathematical impossibility of a solution that is better than `O(N^3)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're also printing the substrings, time complexity goes up to `O(N^3)` because each substring is `O(N)` in length, so you'll be printing `O(N^2)` substrings in `O(N)` time each for an overall complexity of `O(N^3)`. See the duplicate [Find all possible substring in fastest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726641/find-all-possible-substring-in-fastest-way/).

As a side note, you can avoid the empty-string check by changing the inner loop to begin at `i + 1`, which is a (very) slight optimization.

```
s = "abcde"
for i in range(len(s)):
    for x in range(i+1, len(s)+1):
        a = s[i:x]
        print a
```

Comment: This doesn't solve OP problem. He doesn't require a nested loop

Comment: And a solution without nested loop is possible

Comment: It's not about the nested loop, it's about the time complexity. Maybe a solution without a nested loop is possible, but it's impossible to print `O(N^3)` characters in less than `O(N^3)` time.

Comment: This answer is not relevant, this is not what is asked!