# Can you find all substrings of a string in faster than O(N^2) time if your constrained about what sub strings your looking for?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, substring, big-o, trie

According this answer ([Find all possible substring in fastest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726641/find-all-possible-substring-in-fastest-way)). The fastest way to find all possible substrings of a String is `O(N^2)`. However, is this still true if let's say I have a list of words, and I wan't to see if a certain string x has substrings that are in that list of words. For instance, would creating a trie of the list of words, allow me to optimally ignore certain substrings. Thus making the run time better?

Comment: Checking if a string (word) is a substring of a larger string is linear. Checking for K words is still linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is what [string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm) are for.

[image]